# Copy object excepting some fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, copy, spread

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface ObjectOne {
   field1: string;
   field2: string;
   field3: string;
   field4: string;
   field5: string;
   ...
}

public interface ObjectTwo {   
   field2: string;
   field5: string;
   field8: string;
   ...
}
```

Lets imaginate that `ObjectOne` have 20 fields and `ObjectTwo` have 10 fields (all are part of `ObjectOne`).

In the final of an action, I want to assign the fields of `ObjectOne` to `ObjectTwo` (or copy them) avoiding to map each field as:

```
objTwo.field2 = objOne.field2;
objTwo.field5 = objOne.field5;
objTwo.field8 = objOne.field8;
...
```

I know I can destructure `ObjectOne` as:

```
const {field2, field5, field8, fieldX, ...} = objOne;
```

and then assign all these fields to `objTwo` as:

```
objTwo = {field5, field8, fieldX, ...};
```

but I hoped that here exists a better solution (as an inverse of `spread operator`). Spread operator example:

```
const objOne = {...objTwo, field1, field3, field4, field6, ...};
```

If I use spread operator for objTwo, this will inherit all the objOne fields, even if I declare the object type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator, you take one that you don't nee like in my example `one`. Here is an example.

```js
const copyFrom = { one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three' }
const { one, ...rest } = copyFrom

const copyTo = { ...rest } // or just copyTo = rest
```

Comment: thx, but this still force me to destructure the objOne (field by field). In my example, I destructured as required fields and the "rest", your example is with destructuring unrequired fields and the "rest" (clearly inverse, but still not avoided this type of copying)

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(ObjectTwo).forEach(key=>ObjectTwo[key]=ObjectOne[key]);
```

Comment: Much closier for what I need, but I can find a tradeoff here: d The new object must be declared above with all the fields (due of interface type, else I can use a class with constructor). `const objTwo: ObjectTwo = {field2: '', field5: '', field8: '', ...};` So, this "copy style" become unusefull, because I can asign from the initialization the required values as `const objTwo: ObjectTwo = {field2: objOne.field2, field5: objOne.field5, ....};` I don't know if exists something like `const objTwo: ObjectTwo = ObjectTwo.prototype.keys.map(key => {key, value = objOne[key]});` (invalid code, test)

Answer (score 0):

Closest I can get to what you need is this

```
one = {
   field1: "field1",
   field2: "field2",
   field3: "field3",
   field4: "field4",
   field5: "field5"
};

two = {   
   field2: "field2x",
   field5: "field5x",
   field8: "field8x"
};

Object.keys(two).forEach(function(x) { if (typeof one[x] !== "undefined") two[x] = one[x];});

// two is now:
// {field2: "field2", field5: "field5", field8: "field8x"}
```

it's not ideal, but it does only copy defined values from one obj to the other